# How to convert just a h5 file to a tflite file?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run license plate detection on Android. So first of all I find this tutorial: https://medium.com/@quangnhatnguyenle/detect-and-recognize-vehicles-license-plate-with-machine-learning-and-python-part-1-detection-795fda47e922 which is really great by the way.

In the tutorial, we can find `wpod-net.h5` so I tried to convert it to TensorFlow lite using the following :

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('wpod-net.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.post_training_quantize = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("wpod-net.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But when I run this I have this error :

```
  File "converter.py", line 3, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('License_character_recognition.h5')
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 175, in load_model_from_hdf5
    raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
ValueError: No model found in config file.
```

I also tried using the API `tflite_convert --keras_model_file=License_character_recognition.h5 --output_file=test.tflite`  but it gave me the same error.

Does that mean that if I didn't train the model myself I can't convert it to tflite ? Or is there another way to convert the .h5?

Comment: Are you sure the H5 file contains the model ad not just its weights? If it's the second, yo'll first need to build the model yourself (the same way it was built in the tutorial) and then you'll call `model.load_weights('path_to_your_file.h5')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. How can I know if the file contains the model ?

Comment: Well, load_model fails, so I'm guessing it doesn't contain the model. You can also search the tutorial's code for the point where that file is created and see what function they use there

Comment: Ok so it's impossible to convert if we only have the weights that's right ? 
The wpod-net come from here : http://sergiomsilva.com/pubs/alpr-unconstrained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow Lite model incorporates both weights and model code itself. You need to load Keras model(with weights) and then you will be able to convert into tflite model.

Get a copy of authors' [repo](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained), and execute [get-networks.sh](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/blob/master/get-networks.sh). You need only `data/lp-detector/wpod-net_update1.h5` for license plates detector so you can stop download earlier.

Dive a bit into code and you can find prepared load model function at [keras utils](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/blob/master/src/keras_utils.py).

After you get a model object, you can convert it into tflite.

Python3, TF2.4 tested:

```
import sys, os
import tensorflow as tf
import traceback

from os.path                    import splitext, basename

print(tf.__version__)

mod_path = "data/lp-detector/wpod-net_update1.h5"

def load_model(path,custom_objects={},verbose=0):
    #from tf.keras.models import model_from_json

    path = splitext(path)[0]
    with open('%s.json' % path,'r') as json_file:
        model_json = json_file.read()
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(model_json, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    model.load_weights('%s.h5' % path)
    if verbose: print('Loaded from %s' % path)
    return model

keras_mod = load_model(mod_path)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_mod)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me aswell. I understand now why it wasn't working before.