# Tensorflow 2, converting .h5 model to .tflite, missing .pb and .pbtext

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I get this error when trying to convert .h5 model to .tflite

OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /home/xyz/Desktop/facial-expression-recognition-using-cnn-master/model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

The model is saved as .h5 but it does not save a .pb or .pbtext file. Can I have a solution to convert the .h5 file to .tflite please?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know the specifics of tensorflow files, but there are questions about converting HDF5 e.g. [How to convert just a h5 file to a tflite file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598159/how-to-convert-just-a-h5-file-to-a-tflite-file)

Comment: Tried that, I get an error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xyz/Desktop/facial-expression-recognition-using-cnn-master/conv.py", line 22, in <module>
    keras_mod = load_model(mod_path)
  File "/home/xyz/Desktop/facial-expression-recognition-using-cnn-master/conv.py", line 15, in load_model
    with open('%s.json' % path,'r') as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/xyz/Desktop/facial-expression-recognition-using-cnn-master/best_model/saved_model.json'
2.4.1

Comment: `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Convert keras h5 model to tflite

```
tflite_convert \
  --keras_model_file=/tmp/keras_model.h5
  --output_file=/tmp/keras_model.tflite
```

Comment: I tried this but get the following response: "OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)"