# cannot convert h5 model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I downloaded an h5 model i found on the web, i loaded it in my google drive and i try to convert it to tflite.
My code is here (google colab):

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/model.h5")  #here i get the error

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

But i get the error  "No model found in config file."
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. May be issue with `model.h5` file. Did you tried with any other h5 file? Please add full traceback here to investigate the issue. Thanks!

Comment: You need to load `Keras` model with weights and then you will be able to convert into `tflite` model. For more information you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63619212/14290681). Thanks!